# Application Insights requests count metrics vs query don't match

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am trying to retrieve the number of requests for the last day from Application Insights using the API.

- When I do it via the `/metrics/requests/count?timespan=P1D` endpoint
  I get a *sum* of 35871.
- But if I do it via the
  `/query?query=requests | where timestamp > ago(1d) | count;` endpoint
  I get a *count* of 4510.
- Lastly, if I do it via the
  `/events/requests?timespan=P1D&$count=true` endpoint I get a
  *@odata.count* of 4510, the same as from "query".

Why may the requests count difference between metrics and query be so big?

##### Edit:

I have run the following query in Application Insights Logs:

```
requests
| summarize totalCount=sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1d)
```

And that returns (currently it is `12/7/2021, 8:14:47.562 PM`):

```
timestamp [UTC]              totalCount
12/7/2021, 12:00:00.000 AM   35,871
```

That retrieves (I believe) the number of requests *since the beginning of today*.
Surprisingly, that matches the count obtained via `/metrics`:

```
{'value': {'start': '2021-12-06T20:13:46.054Z', 'end': '2021-12-07T20:13:46.054Z', 'requests/count': {'sum': 35871}}}
```

But the range of dates via `/metrics/` covers roughly the last 24h (1d).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `requests` table in "Application Insights Logs" (`/query` endpoint) contains a list of requests where each entry can be the same *name* (uri) but with a different *resultCode*.
I haven't found documentation though that clearly suggests that.

With that assumption I have been able to match the requests count to that of `/metrics`.

Here is the query that I was chasing:

```
let TOTAL = requests | where timestamp > ago(1d) | summarize TotalRequests=sum(itemCount) | extend Foo=1;
let CACHED_TOTAL = materialize(TOTAL);
let FAILED = requests
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| where resultCode hasprefix "4"
| summarize Failed=sum(itemCount)
| extend Foo=1;
let CACHED_FAILED = materialize(FAILED);
CACHED_FAILED 
| join kind=inner CACHED_TOTAL on Foo
| extend PercentFailed = round(todouble(Failed * 100) / TotalRequests, 2)
| project TotalRequests, Failed, PercentFailed;
```